# Know the service name is running

Tags: windows, vb.net, service, windows-services

I have a windows service created by VB.NET that could be more than one. So I have an .exe file (myapp.exe) and with this exe I can install more services (myapp_1, myapp_2, etc).

Is there some method to know, into vb.net code, the name of the service?

Because I tried the `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` but it returns the exe name (myapp) and not the process name.

Thanks

Comment: The value you get from `ProcessName` is the name of the process.  If you want the name of the service then the `Process` class can't help you. You should look at the `ServiceController` class. It's a component so you can add an instance to a form in the designer if you so wish.

Comment: Thanks! I knew this class but I can't get the current `ServiceName` or `DisplayName`, it returns empty string. I initialize it like this: `Dim service As ServiceController = New ServiceController`

Comment: If you simply create an instance like that then it has no association with any actual service. I suggest that you read the documentation to see how the class works before trying to use it.

Comment: I know the component, I should to create an instance of the ServiceController with a parameter (the name of the service) but I haven't the service name. I need something to find the current service name.

Comment: READ THE DOCUMENTATION! Not surprisingly, it lists, describes and explains all the members of the class.  The something you need will be included in that.  VS has a Help menu for a reason.